# Is there a way to make my code not case sensitive and shortcut words?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make it so when a user inputs an option its not case sensitive and they don't have to type the full option. I cant figure out how to do it.

```
package com.unspoken;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String play = "Play a game";
        String internet = "Explore the internet";
        String calculator = "Use the calculator";
        String quit = "Quit Untouched";
        String pickedEvent = "Unpicked";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello, My name is Ghost. What's your name?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        System.out.println("Hello " + name + ". What would you like to do today?");
        while (!pickedEvent.equals("Picked")) {
            System.out.println(play);
            System.out.println(internet);
            System.out.println(calculator);
            System.out.println(quit);
            pickedEvent = scanner.nextLine();
            switch (pickedEvent) {
                case "Play a game":
                    System.out.println("Okay " + name + ", Loading games.");
                    pickedEvent = "Picked";
                    break;
                case "Explore the internet":
                    System.out.println("Okay " + name + ", Loading the internet.");
                    pickedEvent = "Picked";
                    break;
                case "Use the calculator":
                    System.out.println("Okay " + name + ", Loading calculator.");
                    pickedEvent = "Picked";
                    break;
                case "Quit Untouched":
                    System.out.println("Are you sure you want to quit Untouched " + name + "?");
                    String quitAnswer = scanner.nextLine().trim();
                    if(quitAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                        System.out.println("Okay goodbye " + name + ", Have a nice day.");
                        break;
                    }else if(quitAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){
                        System.out.println("What would you like to do today " + name + "?");
                        continue;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you convert the input and comparison string to lowercase before comparison (or uppercase) you will get case insensitive testing.

Comment: My advice would be to look at what methods are available on the String class, some of them may help you achieve your goal(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign numbers to identify the tasks

```
        String play = "1.Play a game";
        String internet = "2. Explore the internet";
        String calculator = "3. Use the calculator";
        String quit = "4. Quit Untouched";
```

and ask user to enter number instead of typing in complete string

```
System.out.println("Hello " + name + ". What would you like to do today?, pick number");
```

and use the numbers in switch case instead of string, change pickedEvent to int

```
        int pickedEvent = 0;
        while (pickedEvent != 4) {
            System.out.println(play);
            System.out.println(internet);
            System.out.println(calculator);
            System.out.println(quit);
            pickedEvent = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

            switch (pickedEvent) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Okay " + name + ", Loading games.");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Okay " + name + ", Loading the internet.");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Okay " + name + ", Loading calculator.");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Are you sure you want to quit Untouched " + name + "?");
                String quitAnswer = scanner.nextLine().trim();
                if(quitAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                    System.out.println("Okay goodbye " + name + ", Have a nice day.");
                    break;
                }else if(quitAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){
                    System.out.println("What would you like to do today " + name + "?");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ok thank you but when i run it after i select 4 it doesnt let me pick yes or no

Comment: @Emma , change `pickedEvent = scanner.nextInt();` to 
`pickedEvent = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());` it will allow you to enter yes or no. i have updated the answer too

Comment: Ty so much heres a cookie:

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
 switch (pickedEvent.toUpperCase()) // changing to uppercase
    {
       case "PLAY A GAME": // select on uppercase
           // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program that selects an option from an array of choices using a case insensitive prefix match.  It does not solve your whole problem, but shows how you can do this kind of selection.

```
public class PartialMatch
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        PartialMatch app = new PartialMatch ();
        app.execute ();
    }

    private String[][] choices = {{"alpha", "A"}, {"beta", "B"}, {"alphabet", "C"}};

    private void execute ()
    {
        check ("a");
        check ("b");
        check ("alpha");
    }

    private void check (String input)
    {
        String choice = selectChoice (input);
        if (choice == null)
        {
            System.out.printf ("For input '%s' no selection was found %n%n", input);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf ("For input '%s' the choice is '%s' %n%n", input, choice);
        }
    }

    private String selectChoice (String input)
    {
        String result = null;
        for (int n = 1; n <= input.length () && result == null; n++)
        {
            result = findChoice (input, n);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String findChoice (String input, int n)
    {
        String result = null;

        String needle = input.substring (0, n).toLowerCase ();
        for (String[] option : choices)
        {
            String key = option[0];
            if (key.length () >= n)
            {
                if (key.toLowerCase ().equals (input.toLowerCase ()))
                {
                    System.out.printf ("Option %s is an exact match%n", key);
                    return option[1];
                }
                if (key.substring (0, n).toLowerCase ().equals (needle))
                {
                    System.out.printf ("Option %s matches at length %s %n", key, n);
                    if (result != null)
                    {

                        System.out.printf ("Key '%s' is ambiguous %n", needle);
                        return null;
                    }
                    result = option[1];
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```